# $.post returns net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to parse a simple html page with jQuery, but when using the shorthand `$.post` method without a data object, I get a `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error.

The following snippet returns the `net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` error:

```
$.post( "http://mofosounds.com:8000/7.html", function(data) {
    console.log("$.post without data object returns: " + $(data).text()); 
}, "html");
```

But providing a data object, which according to the [documents](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/), can be a string or plain object, works:

```
$.post( "http://mofosounds.com:8000/7.html", { dummy: "object" }, function(data) {
    console.log("$.post returns: " + $(data).text()); 
}, "html");

$.post( "http://mofosounds.com:8000/7.html", "Dummy string", function(data) {
    console.log("$.post returns: " + $(data).text()); 
}, "html");
```

The `$.get` method however, which has the same signature and parameters as the `$.post` variant, works without providing a data object. Why is that? Note: Cors must be enabled to parse the url in my example.

Comment: did you try to use `$.post( "http://mofosounds.com:8000/7.html", {}, function(data)`

Comment: What does the response in the network tab of the dev tools look like? I think this is a server error since you're trying to post to an url ending with `.html`, that's usually a static html file.

Comment: According to the docs you've provided, `$.post` doesn't need a data object - so what's causing the ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE?  **Your/The server side code.**  (ie it's expecting a post object, but isn't getting one)

Comment: Why does GET work and not POST?  Well, they're two different HTML Verbs for a start, so it's likely the server will be handling them differently - GET doesn't have a BODY for a start, so the POST handler might be checking for BODY and then throwing that error.